# How do I run an import or export command from mysql workbench outside of mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I see that workbench shows the command being run for imports and exports, and I'd like to run that command on another machine in a standalone script. Unfortunately, the script appears to reference a "defaults file" that is temporary and not accessible after the command runs... it seems that workbench is dynamically creating this extraparams.cnf file each time the command is run.. therefore it makes it difficult for me to reproduce this command elsewhere

```
13:45:52 Restoring /Users/wes/dumps/Dump20170907.sql
Running: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql --defaults-file="/var/folders/x1/8vgyglcd0hv44_5fdlqj1zssm53dzs/T/tmpsmXKI3/extraparams.cnf" --protocol=tcp --host=server.edu --user=riuser --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=prd2 < "/Users/wes/dumps/Dump20170907.sql"
13:46:02 Import of /Users/wes/dumps/Dump20170907.sql has finished
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

BTW: I posted this a month ago on the mysql forums with no response:
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,660219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults file usually holds the username and password.  Ignore what workbench is doing and it will be easier to learn from scratch.

- Read up on the mysql cli options.
- Read up on the mysqldump cli options
- Read up on the options file
- Then realize you should encrypt the password with mysql_config_editor

  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Assuming the commands run on the host local to mysql...

```
mysqldump prd2 --single-transaction --routines --master-data=2 > prd2.sql
mysql prd2 < prd2.sql
```

Add other options as needed.

If on Linux/Unix, and it's a big database, consider `nohup <command> &`, to put it in the background, so you don't have to watch an idle terminal.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. You provided good info and suggestions.  I should also add that I found the following trick to get mysql and mysqldump available in my shell on the mac:
ln -s /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump ~/bin/mysqldump
ln -s /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql ~/bin/mysql

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the accepted answer given by Kevin Bott here is what I did on my Mac as a brutal hack to spy the contents of the defaults file extraparams.cnf.

create a folder writable by any user

```
cd /tmp
mkdir hack
chmod a+xw hack
```

execute the MySQL Workbench export once and leave the Export Progress tab open

replace the mysqldump binary used by the export with a fake that dumps the contents of the defaults file (see Export Progress log for the correct paths to use in your case)

```
cd /private/var/folders/ks/vmng3tc51nb43xkklk7jjxxh0000gn/T/
mv AppTranslocation AppTranslocation.orig
mkdir -p AppTranslocation/10D5E741-FD2F-4247-9CEE-E8A82D8EE23F/d/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS
cd AppTranslocation/10D5E741-FD2F-4247-9CEE-E8A82D8EE23F/d/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS

vim mysqldump

  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 if [ $1 = '--version' ] 
  3 then 
  4     echo 'mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.6.23, for osx10.8 (x86_64)'
  5     exit 0
  6 fi  
  7 
  8 VALUE=`echo $1 | sed 's/^[^=]*=//g'`
  9 cat $VALUE > /tmp/hack/extraparams.cnf

chmod +x mysqldump
```

click 'Export Again' in the Export Progress tab

inspect the contents of the captured .cnf file

```
cd /tmp/hack
cat extraparams.cnf
```

Comment: Nice!.. so was there anything interesting in there besides the login credentials?

Comment: it worked like a charm but there not much inside that cnf file. In my case I had two lines: 
Line 1 >> [client] 
Line 2 >> password="YOUR_PASSWORD"
That's all